# Want to update ListView on index click in bloc flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I've make a about us page in my flutter application where terms,policy & other sections are listed and on click of them I store that index in some variable & I want to open its description below section name.

I successfully done it by using valuenotifier but now I want to convert in into Bloc.

Below are my files,

AboutUsState.dart

```
    import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import '../../../Model/ModelInformation.dart';
    
    @immutable
    abstract class AboutUsState extends Equatable {}
    
    class AboutUsLoadingState extends AboutUsState {
      @override
      List<Object?> get props => [];
    }
    
    class AboutUsLoadedState extends AboutUsState {
    
      final ModelInformation modelInformation;
        AboutUsLoadedState(this.modelInformation);
      @override
      List<Object?> get props => [modelInformation];
    }
    
    class AboutUsErrorState extends AboutUsState {
    
      final String error;
      AboutUsErrorState(this.error);
      @override
      List<Object?> get props => [error];
    
    }
```

AboutUsEvent.dart

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
abstract class AboutUsEvent extends Equatable {
  const AboutUsEvent();
}

class LoadAboutUsEvent extends AboutUsEvent {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class UpdateSelectedViewEvent extends AboutUsEvent {

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}
```

AboutUsBloc.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import '../../../Model/ModelInformation.dart';
import 'AboutUsEvent.dart';
import 'AboutUsState.dart';
import 'Repository.dart';

class AboutUsBloc extends Bloc<AboutUsEvent,AboutUsState> {

  final Repository repository;
    int selectedView = -1;

  AboutUsBloc(this.repository,this.selectedView) : super(AboutUsLoadingState()) {

    on<LoadAboutUsEvent>((event, emit) async {

        emit(AboutUsLoadingState());

        try {
          var dict = await repository.getAboutUs();
          final ModelInformation modelInformation = ModelInformation.fromJson(dict["mainResponse"]);

          emit(AboutUsLoadedState(modelInformation));
        } catch (e) {
          emit(AboutUsErrorState(e.toString()));
        }

    }
    );

  }
}
```

Repository.dart

```
import '../../../Services/ServiceManager.dart';
import '../../../Util/Constant.dart';

class Repository {

  Future getAboutUs() async {

   return await ServiceManager.callWebservice(
        varMethodType: enumMethodType.POST,
        strSuffixPath: ConstantApi.keyGetAboutUs,
        dictParameters: {},
        dictHeaders: {},
        arrayUploadFile: []
    );
  }

}
```

AboutUs.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import '../../Model/ModelInformation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../../Util/Constant.dart';
import 'AboutUs/AboutUsBloc.dart';
import 'AboutUs/AboutUsEvent.dart';
import 'AboutUs/AboutUsState.dart';
import 'AboutUs/Repository.dart';

class ClassAboutUs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  stateClassAboutUs createState() => stateClassAboutUs();
}

class stateClassAboutUs extends State<ClassAboutUs> {

  final AboutUsBloc aboutUsBloc = AboutUsBloc(Repository(),-1);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    aboutUsBloc.add(LoadAboutUsEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return

      WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: ()  async{
          Navigator.pop(context);
          return true;
        },

        child: new Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,

          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0.5,
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
            titleSpacing: 0,
            centerTitle: false,
            leading: BackButton(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground.withOpacity(0.87),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            title: Text("About us",

              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground.withOpacity(0.87),
                fontFamily: ConstantFont.keyPrimaryFont,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body:
          BlocProvider(
              create: (_) => aboutUsBloc,

            child: BlocBuilder<AboutUsBloc, AboutUsState>(

              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is AboutUsLoadingState) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (state is AboutUsErrorState) {
                  return const Center(child:  Text("Error"));
                }
                if (state is AboutUsLoadedState) {

                  ModelInformation modelInformation = state.modelInformation;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
                    itemCount: modelInformation.mainmenu!.informationPages!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                        return

                        aboutUsBloc.selectedView == index ?
                        Container(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.10),
                            child: Column(

                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

                              children: [

                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: (){
                                    aboutUsBloc.selectedView = aboutUsBloc.selectedView== index ? -1 : index;

                                  },
                                  child:
                                  Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [

                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Text("${modelInformation.mainmenu!.informationPages![index].headingTitle}",style: ConstantTextStyle.h2.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary)),
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5,top: 5,bottom: 5),
                                            child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_rounded,size: 15,color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground.withOpacity(0.60),),
                                          ),

                                        ],
                                      )
                                  ),),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,right: 10,),
                                  child: Text("${modelInformation.mainmenu!.informationPages![index].description}",style: ConstantTextStyle.h3.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground.withOpacity(0.87)),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                  ),
                                ),


                              ],
                            )
                        ) :

                         Column(

                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

                          children: [

                            InkWell(
                              onTap: (){
                                  aboutUsBloc.selectedView = aboutUsBloc.selectedView == index ? -1 : index;
                                aboutUsBloc.add(UpdateSelectedViewEvent());
                              },
                              child:
                              Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [

                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Text("${modelInformation.mainmenu!.informationPages![index].headingTitle}",style: ConstantTextStyle.h2.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary)),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5,top: 5,bottom: 5),
                                        child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,size: 15,color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground.withOpacity(0.60),),
                                      ),

                                    ],
                                  )
                              ),),
                            Divider(height: 1,color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground.withOpacity(0.37),),

                          ],
                        );
                    },
                  );
                }

                return Container();
              },
            ),
          )

        ),
      );
  }

}
```

I want to update listview single block based on selectedView value changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one more event for updating selection:

```
class UpdateSelectedEvent extends AboutUsEvent {
  final int selectedView;

  UpdateSelectedEvent(this.selectedView);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [selectedView];
}
```

add this event to your bloc:

```
on<UpdateSelectedEvent>((event, emit) {
    selectedView = event.selectedView;
    if(state is AboutUsLoadedState){
       emit(AboutUsLoadedState(state.modelInformation));
    }
  });
```

and add the update event on onTap:

```
onTap: () => aboutUsBloc.add(UpdateSelectedEvent(index)),
```

Comment: Value changed but view not rebuild, how can I do that in listview itemBuilder return code

Comment: emit(state); should trigger the rebuild.

Comment: Still not working is there something am I doing wrong

Comment: try forcing rebuild with setState on onTap, see if it updates the UI.

Comment: yes it update ui by setstate

Comment: But I can’t understand how that selectValue within event class update state class selectedValue? Can you please explain me how this flow works

Comment: In update event, its updating the bloc's selectedView object value with event.selectedView, passed from the event and then re-emitting loadedState with same modelInfo from event. But having state objects directly in bloc is discouraged as stated in above comment, you should follow that answer's approach.

Comment: Is it required to defined ModelInformation into UpdateSelectedEvent also ?

Comment: no, you can remove it. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

**You shall NOT have your bloc object store state data**, such as "selectedView". Having state variables directly within BLoC objects can lead to tightly coupled components and difficulties in managing state changes. By separating state into dedicated state classes, you achieve better encapsulation and isolation of concerns.

```dart
    @immutable
    class AboutUsLoadedState extends AboutUsState {
    
      final ModelInformation modelInformation;

      // Index of the selected view, if any.
      final int? selectedView;

      const AboutUsLoadedState(this.modelInformation, [this.selectedView]);

      @override
      List<Object?> get props => [modelInformation, selectedView];
    }
```

Then define the event and event-handler which will be used to update the selection.

```
class SelectViewEvent extends AboutUsEvent {
  final int selectedView;

  SelectedViewEvent (this.selectedView);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [selectedView];
}
```

```dart
on<UpdateSelectedEvent>((event, emit) {
      if (state is AboutUsLoadedState) {
         emit(AboutUsLoadedState(state.modelInformation, event.selectedView));
      } else {
        // TODO: Handle other cases
      }
    });
```

And add in your widget trigger that event on tap.

```dart
onTap: () => aboutUsBloc.add(SelectViewEvent(index)),
```

Comment: Thankyou your answer is also helpful